# No matching distribution found for mlx

Tags: python

Attempted to do `pip install -r requirements.txt` here https://github.com/ml-explore/mlx-examples/tree/main/mnist to install mlx and numpy.

That didn't work. Got an error.

Checking out Apple's mlx: https://github.com/ml-explore/mlx-examples/tree/main/mnist

It says to do`pip install -r requirements.txt` to install mlx and numpy.

That didn't work. Got an error saying:

````
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mlx```

Did some googling, saw I could also just do `pip install mlx`. Still got the same error. Help appreciated!
````

Comment: [Please don't post pictures of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). Instead, copy the text itself, [edit] it into your post, and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](/editing-help#code). BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: The `mlx` package requires Python version 3.8 or newer.  What version of Python are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MLX requires Python >=3.8 and it's only available on devices running macOS >= 13.3 It is highly recommended to use macOS 14 (Sonoma). See [docs](https://ml-explore.github.io/mlx/build/html/install.html#).